# VTK reader output

Tags: c++, vtk

I used VTK to read a dicom file and I wanted to get its pixel info. The error was caused by the last line. The error info was `'vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(vtkObjectBase *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'T *' to 'vtkObjectBase *'`. But `typeid(reader->GetOutput()).name()` was actually vtkImageData. Why this error happened?

```
std::string inputFilename = "C:\\Users\\26327\\Desktop\\dll4sw\\data\\SE3\\IM0.dcm";
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader> reader =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName(inputFilename.c_str());
reader->Update();
cout << typeid(reader->GetOutput()).name() << endl;
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> vtkImage = reader->GetOutput();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to show the difference:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> vtkImage = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
cout << typeid(vtkImage).name() << endl;

auto result = reader->GetOutput();
cout << typeid(result ).name() << endl;
```

Might give you some hint.

Comment: Did you try this yourself?

Comment: My output is 
`class vtkImageData * __ptr64   class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkImageData>`

Comment: So how should I init the vtkImageData and get its pixel info

Comment: You can use `auto image = reader->GetOutPut();`  or `vtkImageData* image = reader->GetOutPut();`.